# Wordpress: Randomize Posts & Keep Order on Reload

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a category with 20 posts and I would like to shuffle the posts on the page for each individual user that visits the blog.

I know I can use this to randomize the posts:

```
<?php query_posts('orderby=rand');?>
```

But how do I keep the order after its randomize so its not constantly chagning on refresh?

Comment: The easiest way is to save those id's in that order in a cookie I guess. Or save those server side with a reference ID inside the cookie... But then you can re-order the posts on the next visit if the cookie is set using PHP. At least if you always show the same posts, else you could use the `post__in` parameter to select the same posts as before. Another solution could be writing a custom query within Wordpress, so you can use `FIELD()` to sort the posts in a specific order: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109120/how-does-order-by-field-in-mysql-work-internally

Comment: @ErikvandeVen If I set a cookie, how do I tie the cookie to the order that the posts are in so it doesnt change on reload?

Answer (score 0):

So like I said, the easiest way is to save those id's in that order in a cookie, so the results of your cookie might look like:

```
[12344,13413,13421,44445,12342]
```

You could save the order of ID's inside the database as well and save a reference inside your cookie. A bit more safe but also a bit more work. And I don't know or the ID's of posts are available somewhere in the front-end anyway, so if that's the case I would suggest to just save them inside your cookie.

In your front-end you could check if the cookie is set, if not just get the posts randomly. If the cookie is set you could show them like this:

```
query_posts( array( 'post__in' => $_COOKIE['cookie'], 'orderby' => 'post__in' ) );
```

Comment: do i have to manually store the cookies or is there another way?